# Mocking a class passed as argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have something like this:

```
class ThisClass:
    def my_method(self, param):
        # Do normal stuff
        pass

class OtherClass:
    def my_method(self, param):
        # Do crazy stuff
        pass

def useful_function(some_class, some_param):
    internal = some_class()
    result = internal.my_method(some_param)
    uses_result(result)

# The useful_function can be called with any of the classes
useful_function(ThisClass, 10)
```

What I want to do is to test if `my_method` was called inside `useful_function`. I tried to mock the class and its method, but it did not work:

```
# Inside the test class
def test_case(self):
    MockSomeClass = mock.Mock()
    MockSomeClass.my_method.return_value = 'Some useful answer'
    useful_function(MockSomeClass, 100)
    MockSomeClass.my_method.assert_called_once()
```

The error relies on the fact I use the result of `my_method` in `uses_result`, but the mocked method do not return `'Some useful answer'` as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mock has to account for the instantiation `some_class()` as well:

```
MockSomeClass.return_value.my_method.return_value = 'Some useful answer'

internal = some_class()
internal.my_method() # 'Some useful answer
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Just to complete the answer, the assertion must be done like `MockSomeClass.return_value.my_method.assert_called_once()`. Thank you!